# Hide Detail Point in AchartEngine library

Tags: graphics, graph, bar-chart, achartengine, android-graphview

I want to hide `Detail Point` when using the `AChartEngine libary` as following image.

[image: Detail Point, below the Bar Chart]

I also read the [`AChartEngine Document`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html?help-doc.html) but can not find out the answer,

Please tell me how,

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
renderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

where `renderer` is `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` .